# Remove the entire Date Time part from a column, in R, having DateTime and some other description

Tags: r

I am working to implement Machine Learning in R. I have a column in my data set which has Date-Time followed by some other description. I wish to remove the whole date time from this column.

Example: 
`<13>1 2018-04-18T10:29:00.581243+10:00 KOI-QWE-HUJ vmon 2318 - -  Some Description...`

I wish to get the output with the description part only: `Some Description`

Can you please help me. Thank you.

Comment: You can use regular expression with R. Specifically you’re going to be using something like the grep() function and then specify to extract only the description part. Because you have a “vmon” before the actual description, you may have to specifically deselect the vmon characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option uses `sub`:

```
x <- "<13>1 2018-04-18T10:29:00.581243+10:00 KOI-QWE-HUJ vmon 2318 - -  Some Description..."
sub("^.*\\- \\-\\s*", "", x)

[1] "Some Description..."
```

### Demo